# Spring Boot 3 - server.error.include-message: on-param not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to use `server.error.include-message: on-param` in my `application.properties` file when calling: `throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "message")` but the message does not show. All other properties are set to their defaults. I also tried it as `on_param` but that did not work either.

If I use `server.error.include-message: always` then the message does show, but I want it only to show on-param though because that is more secure.

Can anyone help me understand why on-pram does not work?

I am using spring boot starter web 3.1.4.